# how long does converting to amazon protobuf record using .record_set() take to complete

Tags: python, linear-regression, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to convert a numpy array to an amazon protobuf record using `sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator.AmazonAlgorithmEstimatorBase.record_set()` However, this is taking a really long time.

I'm wondering how the function actually performs and how long it should take

```
from sagemaker import LinearLearner
import numpy as np

model=LinearLearner(role=get_execution_role(),
                             train_instance_count=len(train_features),
                             train_instance_type='ml.t2.medium',
                             predictor_type='binary_classifier',
                                )
```

```
numpy_array = np.array([[7.4727994e-01 9.5506465e-01 7.6940370e-01 8.2015032e-01 1.8113719e-01
  7.8720862e-01 2.9677063e-01 2.6711187e-01 7.9498607e-01 4.4924998e-01
  4.9533784e-01 2.6846960e-01 7.0506859e-01 4.1573554e-01 6.5843487e-01
  3.2448095e-01 4.3870610e-01 7.2739214e-01 6.0914969e-01 5.5108833e-01
  5.8835250e-01 5.5872935e-01 4.4392920e-01 6.8353373e-01 4.7664520e-01
  5.6887656e-01 4.7034043e-01 4.1631639e-01 3.1357434e-01 5.5933639e-04]
 [5.7815754e-01 9.5828843e-01 7.7824914e-01 8.3188844e-01 2.3287645e-01
  7.7196079e-01 2.5512937e-01 2.7032304e-01 7.8349811e-01 5.0130588e-01
  4.8345023e-01 3.8397798e-01 5.9922373e-01 4.7720599e-01 6.7832541e-01
  2.7788603e-01 4.6435007e-01 7.6100332e-01 7.7771670e-01 5.1536995e-01
  5.8536130e-01 5.6407303e-01 5.0898582e-01 6.7815554e-01 3.0614817e-01
  5.7353836e-01 3.8981739e-01 4.1474316e-01 3.1389123e-01 3.5031504e-04]])
```

```
record=model.record_set(numpy_array)
```

### Expected output

I expect the variable record to container a record ready for training with linearlearning model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

```
train_instance_count=len(train_features)
```

This parameter is about infrastructure (how many SageMaker instances you want to train on), not about features. You should set it to 1.

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import LinearLearner
import numpy as np

model=LinearLearner(role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                             train_instance_count=1,
                             train_instance_type='ml.t2.medium',
                             predictor_type='binary_classifier')

numpy_array = np.array(...)

record=model.record_set(numpy_array)
# This takes <100 ms on my t3 notebook instance

print(record)

(<class 'sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator.RecordSet'>, {'s3_data':
's3://sagemaker-eu-west-1-123456789012/sagemaker-record-sets/LinearLearner-
2019-07-18-09-48-21-639/.amazon.manifest', 'feature_dim': 30, 'num_records': 2,
's3_data_type': 'ManifestFile', 'channel': 'train'})
```

The manifest file lists the protobuf-encoded file(s):

```
[{"prefix": "s3://sagemaker-eu-west-1-123456789012/sagemaker-record-sets/LinearLearner-2019-07-18-09-48-21-639/"}, "matrix_0.pbr"]
```

You can now use it for the training channel when you call fit(), re: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_S3DataSource.html

Comment: Thanks. I realised I made that blunder

Comment: It would still be interesting to know how the precoess time can be estimated